# Check duplicate address on contest entry

Tags: duplicates, data-entry

I am building a UK wide competition website that limits entries in a given household/address to 1 per week, and 4 overall.

I need to know the best practice as to what fields to check when seeing if they pass the entry requirement.

I can use house number and postcode, but what is stopping the user saying "Flat xx" , or "Room xx" to get more entries? Using email address would be ineffective, as they can just register a new Gmail address if they want.

They would also "miss-spell" their surname were I to use that as part of the check. Also, who is to say that two people living in the same house won't have the same surname?

Another way I suppose is to use a phone number as a unique identifier. But, people may use all the households phones to increase their entry count?

Is there a tried and tested method that will stop most cases of people entering more that they should?

Answer (score 0):

You could insert their ip address in the validation process, combined with some tricky flash cookies. But that can be avoided also.
So, there is no tested and tried method for this sort of things - Google/Yahoo/M$ all have big problems because of spammers.

You could ask your users to send an SMS number with a tax on it and they receive a PIN number which they can use. Now, the tax you put on that number has to be small enough to not scary them, but big enough to discourage them from sending multiple SMS

Comment: I guess I could use a postcode lookup service, and flag when people opt to enter the address manually.. They should be a low % here, so they can be manually checked daily? That combined with logging the IP should work most affectively?

Comment: They can avoid the ip check by using proxies - the flash cookies instead, can help you detect if the computer was on your site before. Anyway, those can be deleted too. The user can register with different zip codes, he can fake all the information he needs and wants. He can not fake the fact that he's giving you money - so you should use that (paid SMS)